# Create a weekCount column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this data:

```
id    worked_date
-----------------    
1     2013-09-25
2     2013-09-26
3     2013-10-01
4     2013-10-04
5     2013-10-07
```

I want to add a column called `weekCount`. The based date is `2013-09-25`. So all the data with worked_date from `2013-09-25 to 2013-10-01` will have `weekCount` as 1 and from `2013-10-02 to 2013-10-8` will have `weekCount` as 2 and so on. How can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually storing this value in the table or can you compute it whenever you need to determine your range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an approach like this will solve your problem.

I compute an in-memory table that contains the week's boundaries along with a monotonically increasing number (BuildWeeks). I then compare my `worked_date` values to my date boundaries. Based on your comment to @sgeddes, you need the reverse week number so I then use a DENSE_RANK function to calculate the `ReverseWeekNumber`.

```
WITH BOT(StartDate) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('2013-09-25' AS date)
)
, BuildWeeks (WeekNumber, StartOfWeek, EndOfWeek) AS
(
    SELECT 
        N.number AS WeekNumber
    ,   DateAdd(week, N.number -1, B.StartDate) AS StartOfWeek
    ,   DateAdd(d, -1, DateAdd(week, N.number, B.StartDate)) AS EndOfWeek
    FROM
        dbo.Numbers AS N
        CROSS APPLY
          BOT AS B
)
SELECT
    M.*
,   BW.*
,   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BW.WeekNumber DESC) AS ReverseWeekNumber
FROM
    dbo.MyTable M
    INNER JOIN
        BuildWeeks AS BW
        ON M.worked_date BETWEEN BW.StartOfWeek ANd BW.EndOfWeek
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a6ba/6/0)

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. One last question, how do I select the top rank only? For example, if there are 4 ranks in my data. I want to get 4 as integer. Or to put it simpler, I want to count how many ranks were returned. thanks

Comment: I would love to count only unique ranks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would your final, final output look like? The piecemeal approach you are taking with your question is frowned upon here. State all of your needs upfront so people aren't solving intermediate problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `DATEDIFF`:

```
select id, 
    worked_date, 
    1 + (datediff(day, '2013-09-25', worked_date) / 7) weekCount 
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c881c/6)

Comment: Thanks sgeddes, one last thing, is it possible to flip it around by setting weekCount for the data with worked_date from 2013-09-25 to 2013-10-01 as 2 and data with worked date from 2013-10-02 to 2013-10-8 as 1? If there are more records, the weekCount for first week records will keep increasing accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Fiscal Week number, I would use a function that would calculate the week:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FiscalWeek(@FiscalStartDate datetime, @EvalDate datetime)  
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @weekNumber INT = (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FiscalStartDate, @EvalDate) / 7) + 1

RETURN (@weekNumber % 52)
END
GO
```

If you used a fiscal starting date of '2013-09-25' and an evaluation date of '2014-09-25' you would get a week number of 1.

Using a function gives you a little more flexibility to do whatever you need.

Comment: Hello Cam, I am working on pay roll functionality that employees are paid weekly. Wednesday is the first day of the week and 2013-09-25 is wednesday. So I want to display my data weekly. Any idea how I can make use of function for my purpose above? Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  I use to write payroll software back in the 90's and worked on the ledger end of it.  I'm sure we can figure something out.  Just need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant way but this works for me to get the top rank number:

```
WITH CTE AS (

                SELECT employee_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, ''20130925'', worked_date )/7 DESC) AS weekRank
                FROM Timesheet
                )

                SELECT TOP (1) weekRank  
                FROM CTE
                WHERE employee_id=@employee_id  
                ORDER BY weekRank DESC
```

This is how I can create weekRank column and pass a parameter dynamically:

```
WITH rank_cte AS (
SELECT timesheet_id,employee_id, date_worked, 
        dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105')   AS WeekStart, 
        dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105')+6 AS WeekEnd,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, '20130925', worked_date )/7 DESC) AS weekRank
FROM Timesheet

)

 SELECT timesheet_id, worked_date, WeekStart, WeekEnd, weekRank 
 FROM rank_cte rc 
 WHERE  employee_id=@employee_id 
 AND weekRank=@weekRank
 ORDER BY worked_date  DESC
```

Thanks